# nodejs database migration running out of heapspace

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi I am trying to migrate a legacy database into a new database with nodejs.

Some of the legacy database tables have close to a million rows and therefore this is an task comes with high memory consuption.

In my current script I am running out of Heap memory quite fast. I did a number of changes which I hoped would solve this problem however the used space is still growing with iterations.

The following code is basically querying the old table, mapping some fields and inserting into the new database. I have moved the variable declarations from inside the loop to outside in the hopes that the old variables will therefore be overwritten and now new space will be required. Furthermore I use `.pop` on the array hoping this would constantly decrease the space required for the remaining rows.

However as I already said space required is constanly growing with iterations. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
function migrate_user_table(callback) {
    // Migrate user table
    logger.log('info', "Starting migration of user table...");

    let row = null;
    let userid = null;
    let fullname = null;
    let active = null;
    let imagepath = null;
    let statusbase64 = null;
    let gender = null;
    let orientation = null;
    let reports = null;
    let reviewStatus = null;
    let region = null;
    let newReviewStatus = null;
    let newgender = null;
    let neworientation = null;
    let newregion = null;
    let banned = null;
    let lastActive = null;
    let numberOfRequests = null;
    let requestsSend = null;
    let moji = null;
    let created = null;
    let minAgeS = null;
    let maxAgeS = null;
    let minAgeC = null;
    let maxAgeC = null;
    let genderS = null;
    let orientS = null;
    let genderC = null;
    let newgenderS = null;
    let neworientS = null;
    let newgenderC = null;
    let user = null;
    let user_has_social = null;
    let user_has_data_username = null;
    let user_has_data_status = null;
    let user_has_data_report = null;
    let user_has_data_sent = null;
    let user_has_data_recv = null;
    let user_has_moji = null;
    let user_has_filter_searchage = null;
    let user_has_filter_chatage = null;
    let user_has_filter_searchgender = null;
    let user_has_filter_chatgender = null;
    let user_has_filter_searchorient = null;

    legacy.query('SELECT * FROM user u LEFT JOIN behavior b ON (u.userid = b.userid) LEFT JOIN filter f ON (u.username = f.username)', (error, results) => {
        if( error ) throw error;
        while (results.length > 0 ) {
            row = results.pop();

            userid = row["userid"];
            kikname = row["username"];
            fullname = row["fullname"];
            active = row["active"];
            imagepath = row["img"];
            statusbase64 = row["status"];
            gender = parseInt(row["gender"]);
            orientation = row["orientation"];
            reports = row["reports"];
            reviewStatus = parseInt(row["reviewStatus"]);
            region = row["region"];

            // map to new reviewstatus
            newReviewStatus = 1;
            switch (reviewStatus) {
                case 0 :
                    newReviewStatus = 1;
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    newReviewStatus = 3;
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    newReviewStatus = 4;
                    break;
                case -1 :
                    newReviewStatus = 2;
                    break;
            }

            // map to new gender, orientation and region
            newgender = gender +1;
            neworientation = orientation +1;
            newregion = 7;
            if( region >= 0 ) {
                newregion = region +1;
            }

            banned = row["banned"];
            lastActive = row["pendingSince"];
            numberOfRequests = row["numberOfRequests"];
            requestsSend = row["requestsSend"];
            moji = row["moji_idmoji"];
            created = row["created"];
            minAgeS = row["minAgeS"];
            maxAgeS = row["maxAgeS"];
            minAgeC = row["minAgeC"];
            maxAgeC = row["maxAgeC"];

            genderS = row["genderS"];
            orientS = row["orientS"];
            genderC = row["genderC"];

            newgenderS = genderS + 1;
            if( newgenderS === 0 ) {
                newgenderS = null;
            }

            neworientS = orientS + 1;
            if( neworientS === 0 ) {
                neworientS = null;
            }

            newgenderC = genderC + 1;
            if( newgenderC === 0 ) {
                newgenderC = null;
            }

            user = {iduser : userid, imageurl : imagepath, birthdate : null, active : active, banned : banned, reviewstatus_idreviewstatus : newReviewStatus, last_active : lastActive,
                created : created, gender_idgender : newgender, orientation_idorientation : neworientation, region_idregion : newregion};
            connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', user, (error) => {
                if( error ) throw error;
                logger.log('debug', "User Insert successfull");
            });

            user_has_social = {user_iduser : userid, socialtype_idsocialtype : 1, value : kikname};
            connection.query('INSERT INTO user_has_social SET ?', user_has_social, (error) => {
                if( error ) throw error;
                logger.log('debug', "User_has_social Insert successfull");
            });

            user_has_data_username = {user_iduser : userid, datatype_iddatatype : 5, value : fullname};
            user_has_data_status = {user_iduser : userid, datatype_iddatatype : 1, value : statusbase64};
            user_has_data_report = {user_iduser : userid, datatype_iddatatype : 7, value : reports};
            user_has_data_sent = {user_iduser : userid, datatype_iddatatype : 4, value : requestsSend};
            user_has_data_recv = {user_iduser : userid, datatype_iddatatype : 3, value : numberOfRequests};
            datainsert(connection, user_has_data_username);
            datainsert(connection, user_has_data_status);
            datainsert(connection, user_has_data_report);
            datainsert(connection, user_has_data_sent);
            datainsert(connection, user_has_data_recv);

            user_has_moji = {user_iduser : userid, moji_idmoji : moji};
            connection.query('INSERT INTO user_has_moji SET ?', user_has_moji, (error) => {
                if( error ) throw error;
                logger.log('debug', "User_has_moji" +
                    " Insert successfull");
            });

            user_has_filter_searchage = { user_iduser : userid, filtertype_idfiltertype : 1, value : minAgeS, add_value : maxAgeS};
            user_has_filter_chatage = { user_iduser : userid, filtertype_idfiltertype : 2, value : minAgeC, add_value : maxAgeC};
            user_has_filter_searchgender = { user_iduser : userid, filtertype_idfiltertype : 3, value : newgenderS, add_value : null};
            user_has_filter_chatgender = { user_iduser : userid, filtertype_idfiltertype : 4, value : newgenderC, add_value : null};
            user_has_filter_searchorient = { user_iduser : userid, filtertype_idfiltertype : 5, value : neworientS, add_value : null};
            filterinsert(connection, user_has_filter_searchage);
            filterinsert(connection, user_has_filter_chatage);
            filterinsert(connection, user_has_filter_searchgender);
            filterinsert(connection, user_has_filter_chatgender);
            filterinsert(connection, user_has_filter_searchorient);

            logger.log('debug', results.length + " row to go");
        }
        callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that there may be something wrong with your code, considering you are fetching such a large amout of results, I guess it's normal you run out of memory. You can increase the memory by using "node yourScript.js --max_old_space_size=4096" (the number is the amout of megabytes you want to asing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're using `query(stmt, function(error, results) {...})` loads the *entire* result set from your legacy tables into RAM.  You then loop over the contents of that result set row by row (fetching the rows with `pop`.)

Considering that the point of SQL is to handle quantities of data that are too big for RAM, it's no surprise you're running out.

You're doing something wasteful of RAM: `SELECT *`. If you enumerate only the columns you need with `SELECT userid, username, ...` you'll have shorter rows, so more will fit in RAM.

But that won't fix your problem, just delay it.

To fix it you have two choices.  One is to handle the legacy table in chunks.

For example you could retrieve your data in chunks.  You get the first chunk with this query

```
    SELECT whatever ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

and the next chunks with these queries

```
    SELECT whatever ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
    SELECT whatever ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000
```

This gives you chunks of a thousand rows each. Keep going until you get no rows retrieved.

The second choice: investigate streaming the rows of the result set one by one. This requires a slightly different setup for your use of `query()`. It's written up here. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows

Basically it goes like this:

```
var stream =  legacy.query('SELECT whatever');
stream
   .on('result', function(row) {
       // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
       legacy.pause();
       // handle your row of data here...
       legacy.resume();
     })
  .on('end', function() {
     // all rows have been received
   });
```

This will let you handle your data a row at a time.

Comment: Thanks I tried the streaming approach and it helped. However for some reason it is still iterating through all rows before doing any insert, which seems to be the reason the space required is still growing too large.